# What are the standard types of Wi-Fi antenna connectors?

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

What are the standard types of Wi-Fi antenna connectors?

It seems like there is more than one variation of a screw-on type of connector, but I haven't been able to find specifics of what types, sizes, etc. there are.

Comment: I don't know if there's any "list of standards". [Here](http://wireless.gumph.org/content/3/7/011-cable-connectors.html) are some types. For practical purposes: It's whatever is on the hardware already have.

Comment: [Here](https://www.datapro.net/techinfo/wifi_conn.html) is another list (both found by googling).

Comment: I don't know why this question is closed. As worded in both the question and the answer, this question shouldn't be closed as it is not about products, but rather product standards. Closing a question like this as "off-topic" is like closing a question asking about the different CAT ratings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [the link that dirkt has provided to DataPro International Inc.’s website](https://www.datapro.net/techinfo/wifi_conn.html) in [his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1370452/wifi-antenna-connectors?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2062831_1370452), connectors can be categorized as follows:

- **BNC: Round connector with slotted mating collar** – One of the oldest kinds of RF connectors. It is a quick-disconnect used for coaxial cable, meaning it is not only used for Wireless Antenna extensions, but also for video, audio, and networking duties.

  [image: BNC]
- **N-Type: Round screw-type connector, large.** – The largest of the RF connectors, and very common to see on antennae. N-type connectors are usually rated up to 12.5GHz, making them usable in not just WiFi applications, but also in the higher end of the microwave spectrum.

  [image: N-Type]
- **SMA: Round screw-type connector, small.**: The smallest common RF connector. SMA was developed in the 1960's and is rated up to 18GHz.

  [image: SMA]
- **RP-SMA: Round screw-type connector, Reverse Polarity**: Reverse Polarity SMA was designed as a proprietary connector to make it more difficult for consumers to attach larger, potentially illegal antennae to their wireless products.

  [image: RP-SMA]
- **TNC: Round screw-type connector**: TNC is similar to BNC except for the connecting method. Where BNC has a slotted mating collar, TNC has a screw-down type connector. TNC's screw-down connector performs better than BNC in the microwave spectrum.

  [image: TNC]
- **RP-TNC: Round screw-type connector, Reverse Polarity**: Reverse Polarity TNC was designed with the same goals as RP-SMA-- to make it more difficult for consumers to attach larger, potentially illegal antennae to their wireless products. The designers simply applied this methodology to a different connector.

  [image: RP-TNC]