# What are the key things you need to know in choosing a replacement Wi-Fi antenna?

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

What are the key things you need to know in choosing a replacement Wi-Fi antenna? So far I have not been able to find general guidance on this, searches mainly turn up individual product details or someone's very specific problem.

Details which seem to matter:

1. dB rating of the antenna - does this have to match the original exactly? What happens if it differs?
2. Directionality of the antenna - at least whether it covers a specific direction or all around it
3. Anything else? Like antenna materials, length, cover, etc.?

The physical connector also seems to be important, but that [has another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1370452/wifi-antenna-connectors).

The specific scenario I have in mind is replacing a broken antenna, but I've also seen some otherwise nice second hand equipment which is missing antennas - don't want to buy it if that turns out to be a showstopper.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Here is the basic reality of what you are asking… There are two types of Wi-Fi antennas in an extremely broad sense: Indoor antennas and outdoor antennas. For the most part any indoor antenna will behave the same as any other. While some brands such as LinkSys, D-Link and TP-Link have antennas whose physical covering makes them look different, outside of the connector types they are pretty much all the same. So my advice to you is unless you are looking for outdoor gear, don’t worry too much and just get an antenna with a connector that matches your device.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the key things you need to know to choose a replacement WIFI antenna?

They key things is your use case. Which antenna to choose depends on this.

> dB rating of the antenna - does this have to match the original exactly?

No. (And note that the dB rating can depend on the direction; what you really want is a [polar plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pattern#Typical_patterns), but usually that's not available).

> What happens if it differs?

You have an antenna that's better or worse then your old antenna. And if you don't tell the firmware, you may exceed the legal emission power limits for your country.

> Directionality of the antenna - at least whether it covers a specific direction or all around it

Yes, that makes a difference, and it's important.

> The specific scenario I have in mind is replacing a broken antenna,

External antennas matching the existing connector are not hard to find. If the antenna is internal, a broken antenna is rare.

> but I've also seen some otherwise nice second hand equipment which is missing antennas

Again: An external antenna shouldn't be hard to find.